# ASP.NET Gridview - What property exists to find out if the grid renders or not?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-2.0, servercontrols

When there is no DataSource assigned to my grid it doesn't render which is great!

When the datasource is empty it doesn't render - also great :-)

I am implementing some custom navigation so i want to know if there is a property that tells me if the dataview is rendered?

If it is rendered i can show my custom bits otherwise i don't.

Problem an easy answer, but can't figure out which property it is

Anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would checking to see how many rows it has be ok?

```
if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EmptyDataTemplate` to handle what happens when there are no rows.